# sqlContext.tableNames not fetching any hive tables

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I am using CDH 5.8.
When i open the spark-shell
and issue this command:

```
sqlContext.tableNames
res0: Array[String] = Array()
```

I am not getting the hive tables already created.
It should have given me this:

```
res0: Arragy[String] = Array(clickstream)
```

What could be wrong?

hive shell is behaving properly

```
hive> show tables;
OK
clickstream
Time taken: 0.01 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

This is the logs for spark-shell

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ spark-shell
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/flume-ng/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel).
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.6.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.10.5 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_67)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
17/04/01 12:33:49 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Spark context available as sc (master = local[*], app id = local-1491075230633).
17/04/01 12:33:56 WARN metastore.ObjectStore: Version information not found in metastore. hive.metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so recording the schema version 1.1.0
17/04/01 12:33:56 WARN metastore.ObjectStore: Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException
17/04/01 12:33:57 WARN shortcircuit.DomainSocketFactory: The short-circuit local reads feature cannot be used because libhadoop cannot be loaded.
SQL context available as sqlContext.
```

I can clearly see that this could be the issue:

```
17/04/01 12:33:56 WARN metastore.ObjectStore: Version information not found in metastore. hive.metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so recording the schema version 1.1.0
17/04/01 12:33:56 WARN metastore.ObjectStore: **Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException**
```

But what is the resolution for this?
I did the restart of the VM(Ctrl+Alt+Del) also.

Comment: You will have to copy hive configuration files to spark conf directory to enable accessing hive tables in spark. Check this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26360725/accesing-hive-tables-in-spark

Comment: @Pushkr. thanks for the response. But this is CDH5.8 - all this is already there. Moreover that answer is not marked correct out there?

Comment: On CDH everything is there for sure but not everything is configured the way users may want. You can google how to access hive table in spark and you will find similar answers like that post. Spark need to know where hive metastore is and the way you can instruct spark is by copying hive-site.xml to spark conf

Comment: @Pushkr. Thanks - it worked.